# useEffect not aware of state update

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, react-hooks, use-effect

I am facing issue of duplicate element when updating the state in useEffect,
WHat i am trying to do is I get data from firebase and iterate through the data and updating an array with useState, and if the element already exists in in the array, then skip to add that and move to next element. Codes are below

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import {View, FlatList} from 'react-native';


const Users = props => {
const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);
const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);

useEffect(() => {
  (async () => {
      const dbUsers = await db.collection('users').get();
        if (dbUsers.length !== 0) {
          dbUsers.map((filteredUser) => {
            if (dbUsers.exists) {
             const isUserExists = users.find((u) => u.key === dbUsers.id);
              if (!isUserExists) {
                setUsers((prevState) => [
                 ...prevState,
                 new ContactsList(
                 dbUsers.id,
                 dbUsers.data().name,
                 dbUsers.data().number,
                 dbUsers.data().profileAvtar,
                 dbUsers.data().onesignalId,
                ),
             ]);
            }
          }
        });
      }
})();
}, [users]});
```

> setUsers, not reflecting the updated state in mapping the array.

Comment: Is `filteredUsers` defined somewhere, or is it supposed to be `users`?

Comment: sorry i forgot to edit this line, yes filteredUsers are supposed to be users.

Comment: Check if u.key and dbUsers.id are the same data type, for example if both are strings or number

Comment: what exactly is this: dbUsers.id? you get an array of users back  and store it on dbUsers and then you map them as filteredUser, so to which id are you refering?
From my understanding dbUsers doenst have an id...

Comment: Yes both are string, i am also getting the isUserExists = true, but my problem is setUsers are being set twice and after that i am getting the isUserExists = true;

Comment: What i am suppose happening here is that, the whole useEffect events are running in past, that makes the users empty in useEffect, when running.

Comment: the dbUsers.id == doc.id; so i am comparing dbUsers.id in my stored users array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you want to update an array of values, always prefer updating it with a single call to `setUsers` instead of appending values one at a time using multiple calls. With your current implementation, a new call to `db.collection('users').get()` is triggered for each user record it returns, leading to the duplication you're seeing.

Try this:

```js
const Users = props => {
  const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      const dbUsers = await db.collection('users').get();
      const updatedUsers = dbUsers.map(dbUser => {
        // look for an existing user
        const existingUser = users.find(u => u.key === dbUser.id);

        // if we already have the user locally, don't update
        if (existingUser) {
          return existingUser;
        }

        // otherwise, create and return a new user from the remote data
        return new ContactsList(
          dbUser.id,
          dbUser.data().name,
          dbUser.data().number,
          dbUser.data().profileAvtar,
          dbUser.data().onesignalId,
        );
      });
      setUsers(updatedUsers);
    })();
  }, [users]);
}
```

As @lissettdm pointed out, make sure `ContactsList` has a `key` field that is the same type (string or integer) as `dbUser.id`.